# XPath select node where attribute name starts with

Tags: php, html, xml, xpath, domxpath

Given an HTML file looking like this simplified extract:

```
<body>
    <p data-x-foo="...">...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <div data-x-bar="...">...sil</div>
</body>
```

Which XPath expression can I use to select every node containing a "data-x-*" attribute ?

To give a little more context, I'm using PHP and want to query on a DOMXpath object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//*[starts-with(name(@*),"data-x-")]
```

will select all elements with an attribute whose name starts with `"data-x-"`.